# synchronize and serialize function or tasks on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, synchronization

i am stacking on this problem since a week, it's a problem of synchronize on Node JS.
The process that I want to do is :

1- check the existence of table (collection). --> if not insertion of data

2- if the table was created, then i have to find all data on table and compare it with the data that i want to insert.

3- if the new data is already exist on the database (table) the program doesn't do any thing, if not the program inserts the new data to the the database (table).

So we have 3 functions should be scheduled.

**function 1**

```
var getCollection = function(collection, new_theme, nbr_indicateur,callback) {

   dbObject.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections){
    if ( err ) throw err;
    assert.equal(err, null);

    collections.forEach(function(collect){          
      if(collect.name == collection)
         {
            callback(true);

            } 
        else {
          dbObject.collection(collection).insertOne( {
      "name_theme" : new_theme,
      "nbr_indicateur" : nbr_indicateur
   }, function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Inserted a document into the Table_Mapping_Theme collection.");    
  });
            callback(false);
        } 
          });
  });
};
```

**function 2 :**

```
var getData = function(value, collection, theme, callback) {
   var clb = true;
   if(value)
   {
   dbObject.collection(collection).find({}).toArray(function(err, docs){
    if ( err ) throw err;
    assert.equal(err, null);    

    docs.forEach(function(doc){        
    if(doc.name_theme == theme)
         {
            console.log("ce theme existe déja");
            clb = false;

            }  
          });    

  });
  }
  callback(clb);
};
```

**function 3 :**

```
var insertData = function(value, collection, new_theme, nbr_indicateur, callback) {

if(value)
{
  dbObject.collection(collection).insertOne( {
      "name_theme" : new_theme,
      "nbr_indicateur" : nbr_indicateur
   }, function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Inserted a document into the "+collection+" collection.");    
  });

 }
 callback("done");
};
```

calling those functions (app.post using express js)
here i tried with pyramid method but it doesn't work

```
app.post('/setting/add_theme', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) { 

getCollection('Table_Theme', req.body.new_theme, req.body.nbr_indicateur, function(value0){ console.log("0"+value0);
   getData(value0,'Table_Theme', req.body.new_theme, function(value1) { console.log("1"+value1);
      insertData(value1, 'Table_Theme', req.body.new_theme, req.body.nbr_indicateur, function(value2){ console.log("2"+value2);        
      });
   });
});

    res.redirect('/setting');
});
```

Comment: Can you describe how it doesn't work? What do you see on the output?

Comment: Also, as a general observation unrelated to the question you're asking... this is starting to become what we call [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)... I suggest you look into using a Promise library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).